# Can I ask about the business end of providing educational material to universities?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

I work for a company that records medical conferences and have the license and copyright to a great deal of material that doctors value for the needs of their practice and sometimes for their continuing educational credit too.

I've been approached by a mid-sized university regarding one of the items and how we might work out licensing to provide this for their students.

I have questions about what I should expect. Basically, they're asking for the content for free, but being a business, free is not a price we can offer. Is this normal? Should I press them for what the value really is, less a discount perhaps? How does this kind of thing usually work with other post-graduate educational material, such as medical journals? Do they offer subscriptions wholesale for free like that?

May I ask these questions on this site?

Comment: Lol. Went to ask this again just now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think in general those types of questions are fine. Just make sure you split things up into manageable pieces and do not get too focused on your details.